# Как добавить на QPushButton еще одну QPushButton?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qpushbutton

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом в *PyQt5* возможно добавление `QPushButton` на `QPushButton`?

Как я понимаю прямого добавления нет. Подобную работу может выполнить `QItemDelegate`? Или нет?

Необходимо чтобы это встроенная кнопка удаляла текущую кнопку.
Вот как на данный момент реализовано добавление:

**Example.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
                    QPushButton,QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import  pyqtSlot  # noqa
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('resourсes/'))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centrawidget)
        self.city_box = QVBoxLayout(centrawidget)
        self.city_box.setObjectName("City")

        def _createCity(self):
            city1 = QPushButton('Main city \n Population:')
            self.button = 1
            self.anothercity = QPushButton('+', self)

            self.anothercity.clicked.connect(
                lambda x, pb = self.anothercity,layout=self.city_box: self.add_city(pb, layout))


            self.city_box.addWidget(city1)
            self.city_box.addWidget(self.anothercity)

        _createCity(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_city(self, pb, layout):    # Добавление города
        button2 = QPushButton("Город: {}".format(self.button, self))
        self.button -= layout.indexOf(button2)
        self.city_box.insertWidget(self.button,button2)
        self.city_box.insertWidget(self.button+1,pb)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, \
    QGroupBox, QToolBox, QToolButton, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import  pyqtSlot, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.button2m_x = 0
        self.buttons_city = []
        
        self.initUI()
        self._createCity()

    def initUI(self):
        centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centrawidget)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(centrawidget)

        self.scrolllArea = QScrollArea(self)        
        self.scrolllArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.widget = QWidget() 
        self.city_box = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidgetResizable(True) 
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scrolllArea)

        self.anothercity = QPushButton('+', self)
        self.anothercity.clicked.connect(self.add_city)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.anothercity)

    def _createCity(self):
        city1 = QPushButton('Main city \n Population:')
        self.num = 1
        self.city_box.addWidget(city1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.city_box.addStretch(1)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def del_city(self, widget, button2m):
        self.city_box.removeWidget(widget)
        widget.setParent(None)
        widget.deleteLater()
        self.buttons_city.remove(button2m)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_city(self):
        group_w = QWidget()
        group = QHBoxLayout(group_w)
        group.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        group.setSpacing(0)
        
        self.button2 = QPushButton(f"Город: {self.num}")
        self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=self.button2: print(btn.text()))
        
        button2m = QToolButton(self.button2)
        button2m.setIcon(QIcon('img/delete.png'))        
        self.buttons_city.append(button2m)
        
        group.addWidget(self.button2, 1)
        button2m.move(self.button2m_x, 0)  
        button2m.clicked.connect(lambda: self.del_city(group_w, button2m))
        
        self.city_box.insertWidget(self.city_box.count()-1, group_w)  
        self.num += 1
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.button2m_x = self.size().width() - 61
        for button_city in self.buttons_city:
            button_city.move(self.button2m_x, 0)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(200, 300)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, это именно то, как я хотел бы, что бы это выглядело! Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Rett_oo пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял ТС хочет так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я бы кнопку прилепил с краю, но не знаю как это сделать на Qt. Вот лучшее что получилось:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QGroupBox, QToolBox, QToolButton, QHBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import  pyqtSlot, Qt

from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

# ??? sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('resourсes/'))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        self._createCity()

    def initUI(self):
        centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centrawidget)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(centrawidget)

        self.scrolllArea = QScrollArea(self)        
        self.widget = QWidget() 
        self.city_box = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidgetResizable(True) 
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scrolllArea)

        self.anothercity = QPushButton('+', self)
        self.anothercity.clicked.connect(self.add_city)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.anothercity)

    def _createCity(self):
        city1 = QPushButton('Main city \n Population:')
        self.num = 1
        self.city_box.addWidget(city1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.city_box.addStretch(1)


    @pyqtSlot()
    def del_city(self, widget):
        self.city_box.removeWidget(widget)
        widget.setParent(None)
        widget.deleteLater()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_city(self):
        group_w = QWidget()
        group = QHBoxLayout(group_w)
        group.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        group.setSpacing(0)
        button2m = QToolButton()
        icon = QIcon.fromTheme('list-remove')
        button2m.setIcon(icon)
        button2m.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum , QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        button2 = QPushButton(f"Город: {self.num}")
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=button2: print(btn.text()))
        group.addWidget(button2,1)
        group.addWidget(button2m)

        button2m.clicked.connect(lambda: self.del_city(group_w))
        self.city_box.insertWidget(self.city_box.count()-1,group_w)  
        self.num += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(200, 300)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: В целом, не совсем то, но видимо то, что я хочу невозможно сделать в pyqt. Благодарю за ответ! Попробую сделать ориентируясь на Ваш пример.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что правильно понял вас, но предложу попробовать так:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, \
    QPushButton, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea
from PyQt5.QtCore import  pyqtSlot, Qt

# ??? sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('resourсes/'))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        self._createCity()

    def initUI(self):
        centrawidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centrawidget)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(centrawidget)

        self.scrolllArea = QScrollArea(self)        
        self.widget = QWidget() 
        self.city_box = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrolllArea.setWidgetResizable(True) 
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scrolllArea)

        self.anothercity = QPushButton('+', self)
        self.anothercity.clicked.connect(self.add_city)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.anothercity)

    def _createCity(self):
        city1 = QPushButton('Main city \n Population:')
        self.num = 1
        self.city_box.addWidget(city1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.city_box.addStretch(1)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_city(self):                   # Добавление города
        button2 = QPushButton(f"Город: {self.num}")
        button2.clicked.connect(lambda ch, btn=button2: print(btn.text()))
        self.city_box.insertWidget(1, button2)  
        self.num += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(200, 300)
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется он хочет кнопку засунуть внутрь кнопки

Comment: Да, я хотел уточнить какими инструментами возможно добавить кнопку внутрь кнопки, поэтому уточнил, можно ли это сделать с помощью классов  'деделегатов'?

Comment: @Rett_oo объясните лучше что вы хотите сделать, попробуйте как-то показать то, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: мне показалось он хочет https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUiFj.png

Comment: @S. Nick выше человек отправил пример, как я хотел бы что бы это выглядело. Но, видимо, такую задумку не реализовать именно так.

Comment: @Rett_oo все возможно. Я добавил новый ответ - проверьте.